# array of functions in javascript: cannot understand results

Tags: javascript

I can not understand the result provided by an array of functions in javascript

```
 var myArray = [];
 for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
     myArray.push(function(a){
        return i+a;
     })           
 }

 alert(myArray[0](2));
 alert(myArray[1](2));
```

I get 7 as a result for both, as if the value of i for each function in the array was 5.
Could you help me to understand this ?

Comment: That is because the functions are being called after `for` loop has been finished. So the time the function is being executed the value of `i` is `5`.